# Random -2 "unaccept" on a question I didn't ask?

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer

Somehow, I managed to get a -2 to my reputation on Stackoverflow.

The link it points to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145983/pitfalls-of-object-oriented-programming/3137250#3137250 (link to answer that isn't mine)

The reason: "Unaccept"

I don't think I was ever involved in this question at all, so where did this come from?

Comment: Never involved in the question at all? Liar! You left [a single comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145983/pitfalls-of-object-oriented-programming/3137250#comment3223183_3137281) one one of the answers, a year and a half after the question was asked!

Comment: @PopularDemand ah you got me. Ok, I didn't answer or ask the question. Happy? lol

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but the tooltip attached to that "Unaccept" reads "unaccepted an answer." For what it's worth, the system does have different tooltips for the +15 accept case ("answer was accepted") and the +2 accept case ("accepted an answer").

Comment: @kiamlaluno why the rollback to my answer? It's already deleted.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[You asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137217/in-what-situations-is-an-oop-design-approach-suboptimal) that was subsequently [merged into the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/145983/revisions): when it was merged, the answer you accepted on your version of the question was unaccepted, and thus you lost the 2 reputation for accepting it.

Comment: That looks to be the case

Comment: Dang it, Mark. Second time today I was beaten to an answer while writing a comment. Oh well, at least this time my answer was also the right answer.

Comment: @PopularDemand Hah! I'm just surprised I was able to submit my answer before seeing the dreaded "1 new answer to this question" notice. FGITWing is a frustrating game to play.

Comment: Nice catch; here's some more meaningless Meta EXP. (+1)

Comment: @RobertHarvey __!!!WARNING!!!__ your account has been compromised (note the use of the term "EXP" above)